# Undefined class constant 'HASH_SALT_LENGTH', How to check if not defined?

Tags: magento-1.6

I'm working on a custom module that relies upon some properties from Admin user model. I used the method `hashPassword()` in my custom model replicated from core customer model, and in there, there is a call for constant `Mage_Admin_Model_User::HASH_SALT_LENGTH`. When I was working with version 1.9, all was good to go, but then I needed to port the module for 1.6, and there started my problem.
Turns out that above constant is not defined in 1.6, tried with `defined(Mage_Admin_User_Model::HASH_SALT_LENGTH)`, but no success.

Magento 1.6 had the value hard-coded to 2, and 1.9 has this value in constant as 32.

Looking for a better approach than to just hard-code the value so in versions in-between, I can use the same value being used by core code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Mage_Admin_Model_User::HASH_SALT_LENGTH` constant was introduced in *Magento CE 1.8.0.0* – that is *Mage_Admin module version 1.6.1.1*.

So that's where your version switch should be applied like this:

```
$hashSaltLenght   = $legacyValue;
$mageAdminVersion = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('Mage_Admin')->version;
if (version_compare($mageAdminVersion, '1.6.1.0', '>')) {
    $hashSaltLenght = Mage_Admin_Model_User::HASH_SALT_LENGTH;
}
```